# Is there a way to force the iPhone to use its own microphone when connected to a Bluetooth speaker?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, ios

I connect my phone to a Bluetooth speaker to play music. When engage Siri or try to use dictation, the phone wants to use the microphone on the Bluetooth device, which is either too crappy or too far away for it to understand what I am saying.

So, I would like a way to restrict the iPhone to using its own microphone even when connected to a Bluetooth speaker.

I am open to doing this via a setting, buying an app, or jailbreaking or whatever.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See answer given here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126124/better-way-of-using-the-iphone-with-a-bluetooth-speaker

Comment: @DavidI. That was my answer...it sucks!

Answer (score -1):

The simpler solution would be swiping up on the screen and selecting Airplay to select the output mode as iPhone or iPhone speaker, This will make the iPhone mic in use, but it will remove the speaker from Bluetooth as well for the time being.

Comment: This approach does not always work and has drawbacks. Switching airplay, most of the time, switches the iPhone speaker, so what's playing via bluetooth now plays on the iPhone speaker.  

When it works, there is still an added workflow.  I have to pause the podcast, switch the airplay mode, do my dictation, switch bluetooth on airplay again, and the press play on control panel to resume the audio.   Lots of extra work.

I used this method (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126124/better-way-of-using-the-iphone-with-a-bluetooth-speaker) which worked on iOS 8.x, but is broken on iOS9.