# How to force Siri to use phone's microphone when connected to bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, siri, ios

It seems I ask the [same](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126124/better-way-of-using-the-iphone-with-a-bluetooth-speaker/131791#131791) [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213017/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-iphone-to-use-its-own-microphone-when-connected-to-a) [after](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126124/better-way-of-using-the-iphone-with-a-bluetooth-speaker) every release of iOS.

I want to be able to use phone's own microphone for Siri when connected to Bluetooth in the car.  The reasons for that are many, but chief among them - Bluetooth sucks.

Is this feature present in iOS 12?

Comment: Ditto!  No idea why but my car's mic only works for phone calls, not Siri.  It just sits there... staring at me... ignoring my words.  Frustrating as hell!!!

Comment: @MarqueIV I did find a workaround of sorts - not a good one.  If your car has a Mic button (or Voice Recognition button), click that instead of firing up Siri.  That will bring up Siri on your phone almost immediately (usually).  Anyway, it works in my car.

Comment: @MarqueIV But it would be great if Apple fixed this problem.  I've been submitting this bug to them since iOS 8.